# Why is linear search so much faster than binary search?

Tags: c++, linux, optimization

Consider the following code to [find a peak](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-peak-in-a-given-array/) in an array.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<unistd.h>


using namespace std;

//Linear search solution
int peak(int *A, int len)
{
    if(A[0] >= A[1])
        return 0;
    if(A[len-1] >= A[len-2])
        return len-1;

    for(int i=1; i < len-1; i=i+1) {
        if(A[i] >= A[i-1] && A[i] >= A[i+1])
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int mean(int l, int r) {
    return l-1 + (r-l)/2;
}

//Recursive binary search solution
int peak_rec(int *A, int l, int r) 
{
    // cout << "Called with: " << l << ", " << r << endl;
    if(r == l)
        return l;
    if(r == l+ 1)
        return (A[l] >= A[l+1])?l:l+1;

    int m = mean(l, r);

    if(A[m] >= A[m-1] && A[m] >= A[m+1])
        return m;

    if(A[m-1] >= A[m])
        return peak_rec(A, l, m-1);
    else
        return peak_rec(A, m+1, r);
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int size = 100000000;
    int *A = new int[size];
    for(int l=0; l < size; l++)
        A[l] = l;

    chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();   
    int p = -1;
    for(int k=0; k <= size; k ++)
//      p = peak(A, size);
        p = peak_rec(A, 0, size-1);

    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now(); 

    chrono::duration<double> time_span = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(end - start);

    cout << "Peak finding: " << p << ", time in secs: " << time_span.count() << endl;

    delete[] A;
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile with -O3 and use the linear search solution (the `peak` function) it takes:

```
0.049 seconds
```

If I use the binary search solution which should be much faster (the `peak_rec` function), it takes:

```
5.27 seconds
```

I tried turning off optimization but this didn't change the situation.  I also tried both gcc and clang.

> What is going on?

Comment: with a sorted array, like you give as input, the linear solution terminates before entering the loop (due to the second if)

Comment: thats not a binary search. A binary search reduces the number of candidates in each step by a factor of 2, while you just increment/decrement the index by 1. It is basically also linear with the difference that it is recursive

Comment: @NathanOliver Typo fixed. Thanks.

Comment: This is a complete waste of resources. Binary search is when you to look for a given element in a sorted container. If you want the minimum or the maximum, then even a linear search is over the top. Here, there is no reason for a binary search or a linear search.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher The task is to find a peak in the array. Binary search is a great way to do this.

Comment: @Anush no it is not. Imagine all elements being 0 and a single one being eg 100. To be sure where the peak is you need to traverse every single entry anyhow

Comment: @user463035818 That's not true.  First note that two elements that are the same as their neighbour count as a peak. It is only if one neighbour is bigger and the other smaller that you are not at a peak. Does that help?

Comment: maybe you should include your definition of "peak" in the question ;) Yours seems to be completely different from what I think is a peak

Comment: anyhow in an unsorted array binary search really makes no sense. Binary search is based upon dividing the whole interval into two and knowing by the values of only the elements at the edges that what you are looking for can only be in one of the two intervals.

Comment: lets say you look for a value close to 13, then in [ 1,2,3,5,8,10,15,21] you know that the best match cannot be between the elements 1 and 5 but it must be between 5 and 21, so you can exclude half of the values in a single step, hence "binary"

Comment: sorry, didnt follow the link where there is a definition of "peak", though i would say that this is a definition useful in the context of this exercise only. Rarely it makes sense to say that an array containing only zeros is full of peaks...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What is going on is that you've tested it in one case of a strictly monotonically increasing function. Your linear search routine has a shortcut that checks the final two entries, so it never even does a linear search. You should test random arrays to get a true sense of the distribution of runtimes.

Comment: Doh! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because your linear search solution has an optimization for sorted arrays as the one you are passing into it. `if(A[len-1] >= A[len-2])` will return your function before even approaching to enter the search loop when your array is sorted uprising so the complexity there is constant for rising sorted arrays. Your binary search however, does a full search for the array and thus takes much longer. The solution would be to fill your array randomly. You can achieve this by using a random number generator:

```
int main() {
    std::random_device rd; /* Create a random device to seed our twisted mersenne generator */
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); /* create a generator with a random seed */
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> range(0, 100000000); /* specify a range for the random values (choose whatever you want)*/
    int size = 100000000;
    int *A = new int[size];
    for(int l=0; l < size; l++)
        A[l] = range(gen); /* fill the array with random values in the range of 0 - 100000000
[ . . . ]
```

EDIT:

One very important thing when you fill your array randomly: your function will not work with unsorted arrays since if the first element is grater than the second or the last one is greater than the previous, the function returns even if there was a value inbetween which is much greater. So remove those lines if you expect unsorted arrays (which you should since a search a peak element is always constant complexity for sorted arrays and there is no point in searching one)

Comment: This isn't a good worst case either sadly as linear search will find a peak almost instantly with high probability.

Comment: @Anush i a added a note to clearify the problem with the code